# Copy Code Exchange - copy code to clipboard from Stack Exchange sites!

Tags: script, questions, answers

### Screenshot

- ##### Dark Mode

> [image: userscript preview - dark mode]

- ##### Light Mode

> [image: userscript preview - light mode]

### About

This is a userscript to copy code (from any [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) element) to the clipboard from all Stack Exchange sites. It's pretty nice and cool to be able to copy the code faster, rather than manually selecting it all then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

### Download

It's all hosted on GitHub Gists, no need for a whole repository.

*Direct Link:* [Unminfied](https://gist.github.com/lightningmcqueen80/9c6ea4432e7749fdd67824076b8506f9/raw/d9af7219c6aa159a244283a33cfd4c11fbe8aa71/copyCodeExchange.user.js) - [Minified](https://gist.github.com/lightningmcqueen80/4c80f54f571e76a7ff7336bfb6ccdc8e/raw/fba9129799fd9a55a34a674305e18692fd2b64cc/copyCodeExchange.min.user.js).

*Gists:* [Unminfied](https://gist.github.com/lightningmcqueen80/9c6ea4432e7749fdd67824076b8506f9) - [Minified](https://gist.github.com/lightningmcqueen80/4c80f54f571e76a7ff7336bfb6ccdc8e).

### Compatibility

The userscript should work across all modern browsers and all userscripts managers.

Every time a code is copied, either a confirmation message is written to the console or an error message, so be sure to check if you meet any problems. It's all done using the [*Clipboard API*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API).

### Contact and issues

If you meet any problem, it's best to write an answer below with a screenshot of the problem, browser version, userscript manager name, and version for testing purposes.

Feature requests are also welcome, but I tried to make the userscript work for *all* people.

Contributing is also welcome if you have better ways to do the same exact thing, or if you can save 1 or 2 lines.